# How to use 1k external monitor with 4k Dell Precision laptop

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a 4k Dell Precision 5510 laptop, and I need to add a 1k external monitor to it, but I can't get the resolutions to get along. If I use @2x scaling, everything looks comically large (and unusable) on the 1k monitor, while if I use @1x scaling, stuff on the laptop builtin 4k display becomes unreadable.

**How do I use @2x scaling on the laptop display, but @1x scaling on the external monitor?**

I have a 4k monitor, but I can't use it because the lag is terrible, *even with the correct nVidia drivers installed and the card activated*. (Curiously, the builtin display still functions fine, it's just the 4k external monitor that lags). I also tried using the laptop builtin display at half resolution, but for some reason it does really destructive interpolation and it comes out looking like a bad jpeg.

If this is not possible in the unity desktop, can someone direct me to a desktop that does support multiple scaling?

Comment: Did you solve the scaling issue? In terms of lag, are you using a Displaylink dock by any chance? I've noticed something similar. Plugging the monitor via either hdmi or thunderbolt will fix the lag. Displayport brings the frames per second via intel graphics down to about 1, which causes the problem.

Comment: no, i fell back to a 1K monitor. Also 1Hz frequency is far, far worse than what I experienced

Comment: I get 1hz when running glxspheres64.